# Overlaying bar charts in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, charts

Can I overlay 3 barcharts in python? The code I used to produce the three barcharts can be seen below:

````
fig3.set_title('Sample 2(2019-10-05)- Averge bikes used per hour')
fig3.set_xlabel('Hour')
fig3.set_ylabel('Average Percentage')
fig3.set_ylim(ymin=70) ``` 

fig4=average_bikes_used_hours3.plot.bar(y='Average bikes used in a hour', x='hour',figsize=(20,10))
fig4.set_title('Sample 3(2019-08-31)- Averge bikes used per hour')
fig4.set_xlabel('Hour')
fig4.set_ylabel('Average Percentage')
fig4.set_ylim(ymin=70)

fig5=average_bikes_used_hours4.plot.bar(y='Average bikes used in a hour', x='hour',figsize=(20,10))
fig5.set_title('Sample 4(2019-08-31)- Averge bikes used per hour')
fig5.set_xlabel('Hour')
fig5.set_ylabel('Average Percentage')
fig5.set_ylim(ymin=70)
````

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive way is:

- create a **single** DataFrame,
- with index for consecutive hours,
- with separate columns for each sample.

Something like:

```
      Sample 2  Sample 3  Sample 4
Hour                              
8           20        25        21
9           22        27        27
10          23        34        29
11          21        30        22
12          19        22        24
```

Then just plot:

```
df.plot.bar();
```

and you will have all samples in a single picture.

For the above data, I got:

[image]

If you want some extra space for the legend, pass *ylim* parameter, e.g.:

```
df.plot.bar(ylim=(0,40));
```